# Querying Mongo DB - Using IN filter in embedded class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

Consider the below Document structure (**users**)

```
id user_id phone

1  Balan   {0   - id = adsfasf232332  - number = 908767778}, 
                       ...........{1   - id = adsf343fadfasd - number = 22232323}
2  Kumar   {0   - id = adsfasf24442  - number = 2727272}
```

What is the Mongo model query equivalent of below query

```
select * from  users where user_id = "Balan" and phone_number in (22232323)
```

i tried with below query, but its not helpful

```
temp = User.where(user_id: => "Balan").where('phone.number' => "22232323")
```

what am i doing wrong?

**NOTE : The class Phone is embedded in class User.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Mongoid 3, you can say

```
temp = User.where(user_id: 'Balan').in('phone.number' => ['22232323'])
```

This query syntax is provided by Origin (a dependency of Mongoid now). [[1]](http://mongoid.org/en/origin/docs/selection.html)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:

```
temp = User.where(user_id: => "Balan",:'phone.number'.in => ["22232323"])
```

OR if you want to run differently

```
temp = User.where(user_id: => "Balan").where(:'phone.number'.in => ["22232323"])
```